# Weird switch behavior in .NET 4

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, switch-statement

I have a problem understanding what's causes the compilation error in the code below:

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        dynamic x = "";
        var test = foo(x);

        if (test == "test")
        {
            Console.WriteLine(test);
        }

        switch (test)
        {
            case "test":
                Console.WriteLine(test);
                break;
        }
    }

    private static string foo(object item)
    {
        return "bar";
    }
}
```

The error I get is in `switch (test)` line:

```
A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, 
enum, or corresponding nullable type.
```

Intellisence shows me that foo operation will be resolved on runtime, which is fine because I'm using a dynamic type as a param. However I don't understand how `if` condition compiles fine when switch doesn't.

Code above is just simplified version of what I have in my application (VSTO) which appeared after migrating the app from VSTO3 to VSTO4 when one method in VSTO was changed to return `dynamic` type values instead of `object`.

Can anyone give me an explanation what's the problem. I know how to resolve it but I'd like to understand what's happening.

Comment: Looks like you can't ducktype a switch

Comment: As `switch` isn't defined for every possible object type

Comment: Everyone seems to be answering as if the question is "Why can't I `switch` on a `dynamic`?" I think the question really should be "Why is `test` typed as `dynamic` in the first place?" I get that *if* `foo` had overloads which returned different types, `test` would have to be `dynamic`; but since it *doesn't*, I'm still having trouble figuring out the answer to the "real" question here.

Comment: I suspect it's in the C# spec - if an expression has a `dynamic` input, then the output is also `dynamic`, irregardless of whether there's only one possible interpretation of the expression (because, say, you could add another method using reflection)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you're calling a method dynamically, the result is also a `dynamic` (as the return value could be *anything* - it doesn't know until runtime). And you can't `switch` on a `dynamic` variable type.

Comment: And it's ok to `if` on `dynamic`?

Comment: @RaYell: You don't "`if` on `dynamic`" - you compare for equality `==` on `dynamic`. That's well defined.

Comment: Why could the return value be anything? `foo` returns a `string`. I must need to read up on this `dynamic` craziness...

Comment: @Dan, because there could be multiple overloads of foo, and because x is dynamic you can't decide exactly which will get called until x's type is known which won't happen until runtime.

Comment: @Dan Tao: Bill Wagner gives a good explanation in Effective C# (IMO)

Comment: @Simon: There *could* be multiple overloads of `foo`, but in this case there is not, right? Doesn't it seem like the compiler should know what the return value will be if there's only one version of the function out there?

Answer (score 3):

The type of the switch expression is evaluated by the compiler, at compile time. The type of `dynamic` is evaluated in runtime, so the compiler cannot verify whether it is (or is convertible to) one of  the allowed types (which, according to the [C# 4 Language Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=DFBF523C-F98C-4804-AFBD-459E846B268E&displaylang=en) is sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, bool, char, string, or an enum-type).

Answer (score 2):

As Matt Ellen says, but with a little more background.

For the `switch` statement: from the C# Language Specification v4.0:

The ***governing type*** of a `switch` statement is established by the switch expression.

- If the type of the switch expression is `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `bool`, `char`, `string`, or an *enum-type*, or if it is the nullable type corresponding to one of these types, then that is the governing type of the `switch` statement.
- Otherwise, exactly one user-defined implicit conversion (§6.4) must exist from the type of the switch expression to one of the following possible governing types: `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `char`, `string`, or,  a nullable type corresponding to one of those types.
- Otherwise, if no such implicit conversion exists, or if more than one such implicit conversion exists, a compile-time error occurs.

---

For the `if` statement the expression is evaluated as a Boolean operation. The expression evaluation is deferred to run-time because of the use of `dynamic` in the method call in the variable assignment. From the specification above, it looks like `switch` requires compile-time evaluation of switch types.

Answer (score 0):

That is some unexpected behavior - I would have expected a var set to a method that explicitly returns a string to properly infer a string type.  Oh well.....

If you replace:

var test = foo(x);

with:

string test = foo(x);

it all compiles as you know.

This is safe since you've declared foo() as returning a string, and perhaps a little more intuitive to read in the long run anyways.

Comment: the 'var' can't be resolved at runtime because x is dynamic. There could potentially be multiple overloads of 'foo' that have different parameters and return types. Exactly what happens can't be resolved until the type of x is known, which won't happen until runtime. what actually happens is that var gets resolved to 'dynamic' which is why it can't be used in the switch. If you hover your mouse pointer over the 'var' you will see visual studio is resolving it to 'dynamic'

Comment: Yes - I'm seeing that.  I guess I just assumed that the var inference was smarter when faced with the presence of a single method in the scope where the method call was made.  But you know what they say about assumptions.... =)

Answer (score 0):

Switch statements only support numbers, chars, enums and strings. `dynamic` is none of those things. If you assume that `x` is a string, you can just cast it:

```
dynamic x = ""; 
string test = (string)foo(x);
```

You'll just get a runtime error if it's not.